# Shared folders don't "exist" in Linux guest (VMWare)

Tags: linux, vmware

I have a Windows host running a Linux guest and I've created a shared folder. It appears under `/mnt/hgfs/` as expected. When I use `ls` I can see the folder. But, when I try to `cd` into the folder it claims that there is no such file or directory. Auto-completion doesn't work either; I can see the folder but it doesn't seem to "exist". I tried making a symbolic link too but it claims to be broken right after creation. What's going on here?

```
x@ubuntu:/mnt$ ls -laF /mnt/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Oct 13 14:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 Oct 13 14:35 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 13 14:52 hgfs/

david@ubuntu:/mnt$ ls -laF /mnt/hgfs/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 13 14:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 13 14:52 ../
```

Comment: Did you install VMware Tools?  The Tools are essential for shared folders

Comment: What is the user/group of that directory? Change to root before entering that directory.

Comment: Please append output of `ls -laF /mnt/` and `ls -laF /mnt/hgfs/` to your question.

Comment: @John yes. I installed and reinstalled VMware Tools using Manage->Reinstall VMWare Tools

Comment: Weird. Does `mount | grep hgfs` give you some unusual output?